# Cannot run cshtml configured within an Area

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have an Area defined in the MVC project named Account and under views in this Area I have Logon.cshtml. In web.config, I got following

```
 <authentication mode="Forms">
    <forms loginUrl="~/Areas/Account/LogOn" timeout="600" />
  </authentication>
```

I am using Authorize attribute on my controllers but when I run the project, get following error

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   The resource cannot be found.
>   Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly.
>   Requested URL: /Areas/Account/LogOn

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The name of your area is named "Areas"?

Comment: When you add an area in MVS, it adds a folder named "Areas" by default and all areas you add goes under this "Areas" folder. The  area I created is named "Account". So physically all files are under "Areas\Account" .

Comment: The area is named "Account"?  That's strange, because there's usually already a *controller* named `AccountController`.  And `LogOn` sounds like an *action* and not a *controller*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the files are stored in a folder named `Area`, this does not mean that the routing to this file is `/areas/account/logon`.

Review the `AccountAreaRegistration.cs` in the Account folder.  The `AreaName` defined in this file (most likely `Account`) is the initial portion of the route to the area.  Also, the `context.MapRoute` line will have the default Route for your area.

In all likelihood, especially if you did not edit the area registration file, the correct path to put in web.config is `~/account/logon`.